# What are some ways to deploy a reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

So, I have spent a couples of months learning react and have now created a react app that works nicely on my local computer using the web address localhost:3000. But now is the big question: how do I deploy the app so it becomes accessible on the internet for everybody to see. Previously I have place on a web hotel where I can host some php files. But how do I put the react app on that web hotel. Or do I need some other service that a normal web hotel cannot handle.

Thanks for any help

/Simon :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few great options for pushing out your first React application. Once it's built and hosted on GitHub, there's a few free options for deploying static websites (as long as your app meets this requirement). I suggest checking out GitHub Pages (https://pages.github.com/) or Netlify (https://www.netlify.com/); they offer you the tools to deploy right from your repository.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is simply run `npm run build` or  `yarn build` [command](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build) then the scripts try to create a js file and a CSS file and a HTML file and all your files can access from `build` folder. so just copy build folder and everything in it to server for example upload it to Heroku or AWS

Answer (score 0):

First you should create build. Use 'npm run build' or if you are using yarn then use 'yarn build' command.
After that you will see build folder in your app having html file static folder.

You can test with any local server in your machine. You can use following chrome extension to deploy your app locally. Just import your build folder inside this extension.
[Web server for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Keith!

I used "Github pages" to deploy my React app and it was surprisingly simple. I found a great short 5 minute tutorial on Youtube: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y-PqBH-htk". This is how I did it:

1. Added this line to my package.json file, at the top level:
   "homepage": "https://zimon42.github.io/helloworld"
   (zimon42 is your username on Github. helloworld is the name of your repository)
2. Installed the so called Github pages module by running:
   npm install --save gh-pages
3. Added these two lines to my package.json file, under scripts:
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
4. Committed and pushed everything to Git (Dont know if this step is necessary)
5. Deploying the application by running
   npm run deploy
6. Now simply check out the paeg at https://zimon42.github.io/helloworld.
   ( For me there was a delay before the changed took effect.)

Also my routes didn't work. Got a empty page. But saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yA7BGos2KQ&t=114s which described using HashRoutes instead, and then it worked!

/Simon :-)